# No input validation in node webkit (nw.js) based app

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, node-webkit, nw.js

This is my HTML code

```
<input type="text" required="" placeholder="Username">
```

which basically make the username necessary for form submission and displays a tooltip for the field if left black on submission.

**The HTML Page works fine, output:**
[image]

---

### However on running the genrated app.exe file, there are no messages, output:

[image]

**My Question:
Is this a Node Webkit limitation? Are there any workarounds?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **IS** a nw.js limitation.

The tooltip is generated by **Chrome** the browser in your former image, but nw.js does not have the same version as Chrome as you are using, so its support for HTML5 stuff like this is expected to be sub-par.

I can't find any references for this claim, but this is most likely what's happening.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I was worried that this would go unanswered.
Alright, so the browser engine bundled with nw.js doesn't support it. Are there any workarounds to this? What if I validate using jQuery Validate plugin?

Comment: @Ashesh javascript/jquery would be the way to go with this. You probably don't need the validate plugin though.

Comment: yeah, I finally settled on plain JS. It was getting overly complicated to work with.